# Weak wifi on DSL wifi router; might run cable. Maximum cable length?

Tags: wireless-networking

I've got a DSL wifi router on the ground floor, and a really weak signal strength upstairs. I thought about running cable, but if there are any other alternatives on a budget, I'm all ears.

If I have to run cable, what's the maximum length I could do with ethernet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Practical limits are around 100 meters. But, it can be more, it can be less, mostly depends on your cable quality (good shielding is important) and cabling skills (wires must be paired properly).

Alternative to cable (or if it is preferable choice for you), would be to purchase wifi AP from same manufacturer, that doesn't have DSL capabilities, but has WDS capabilities (presumably, your DSL wifi router also has WDS). That way you could easily extend coverage of your current wifi network.

Comment: WDS? I'm not familiar. My buddy has an extra NetGear N router lying around. Wonder if we could use that as a repeater? Or is the correct term "extender"?

Comment: WDS: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Distribution_System - you can use any device which supports security settings used at your base AP (which is very likely), and both devices have to support WDS (which is less likely, but possible). Look up "repeater mode" for your and your buddy's router.

Answer (score 0):

100 meters. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_twisted_pair .

Answer (score 0):

Get a Pair of powerline adaptors

[How can I expect PowerLine Networking to work?](https://superuser.com/questions/247345/how-can-i-expect-powerline-networking-to-work)

[Powerline network adapters vs wireless range extender](https://superuser.com/questions/237636/powerline-network-adapters-vs-wireless-range-extender)